# get aoColumnDefs and aoColumns from $.getJSON request from server?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

i have just started using datatables 1.9 jquery plugin but facing to get datatables configuration from server side.
my datatables code is :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./viewController",
        data:{ "TableName" : "ViewGridDept",
        "Call" : "gridConfiguration"},
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data){
        //columns=data.aoColumns;
        var coldata = eval( '('+data+')' );
        alert(coldata.aoColumns);
        employeeTable = $("#EmployeeTable").dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI" : true,
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        "bFilter": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource" : "./viewController",
        "aoColumns":coldata.aoColumns ,
        "aoColumnDefs":coldata.aoColumnsRef,
        "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
            aoData.push( { "name" : "TableName", "value" : "ViewGridDept" },
            { "name" : "Call", "value" : "Data" } );
            $.ajax( {
                    "dataType": 'json', 
                    "type": "POST", 
                    "url": sSource, 
                    "data": aoData, 
                    "success": fnCallback
                    } );}
```

and my json from server side is

```
{"aoColumns":[{"mDataProp":"deptName","sTitle":"Department Name"},{"mDataProp":"deptId","sTitle":"Department Id"}],"aoColumnsRef":[{"aTarget":["2"]},{"aTarget":["1"]}]}
```

but my datatables not loading the data.my question is how to use nested json for datatable `"aoColumns":coldata.aoColumns ,
            "aoColumnDefs":coldata.aoColumnsRef,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string sColumns Deprecated Optional is the main cause of that issue.now i am using oaColumnDefs for that my working code is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var columns;
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./viewController",
        data:{ "TableName" : "ViewGridDept",
        "Call" : "gridConfiguration"},
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(coldata){
        //columns=data.aoColumns;
        //var coldata = eval( '('+data+')' );
        alert(coldata.aoColumnsRef);
        employeeTable = $("#EmployeeTable").dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI" : true,
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        "bFilter": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource" : "./viewController",
        //"aoColumns":coldata.aoColumns ,
        "aoColumnDefs":coldata.aoColumnsRef,
        //"aoColumnDefs":[{"sTitle":"Department Name","mDataProp":"deptName","aTargets":"[1]"},{"sTitle":"Department ID","mDataProp":"deptId","aTargets":"[0]"}],
        "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
            aoData.push( { "name" : "TableName", "value" : "ViewGridDept" },
            { "name" : "Call", "value" : "Data" } );
            $.ajax( {
                    "dataType": 'json', 
                    "type": "POST", 
                    "url": sSource, 
                    "data": aoData, 
                    "success": fnCallback
                    } );}

});
        }
```

});

and json for the first request is now :

```
{"aoColumnsRef":[{"aTargets":[1],"mDataProp":"deptName","sTitle":"Department Name","bVisible":true,"bSearchable":true},{"aTargets":[0],"mDataProp":"deptId","sTitle":"Department Id","bVisible":true,"bSearchable":false}]}
```

hope it helps to those how face this problem.

Comment: why are you using `POST`?

Answer (score 2):

Your reply from the server isn't well-formed like your datatables expects.

> > Reply from the server
> >
> > In reply to each request for information that DataTables makes to the server, it expects to get a well formed JSON object with the following parameters.
> >
> > int   iTotalRecords   Total records, before filtering (i.e. the total number of records in the database)
> >
> > int   iTotalDisplayRecords    Total records, after filtering (i.e. the total number of records after filtering has been applied - not just the number of records being returned in this result set)
> >
> > string    sEcho   An unaltered copy of sEcho sent from the client side. This parameter will change with each draw (it is basically a draw count) - so it is important that this is implemented. Note that it strongly recommended for security reasons that you 'cast' this parameter to an integer in order to prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.
> >
> > string    sColumns    Deprecated Optional - this is a string of column names, comma separated (used in combination with sName) which will allow DataTables to reorder data on the client-side if required for display. Note that the number of column names returned must exactly match the number of columns in the table. For a more flexible JSON format, please consider using mData.
> >
> > array aaData  The data in a 2D array. Note that you can change the name of this parameter with sAjaxDataProp.

You can find that info here http://www.datatables.net/usage/server-side

Comment: you are right but i have two ajax requests .first request for get   columns configuration and second ajax request to get the data to show in table.

Comment: i figurout my problem it was "aoColumns".i have now put aTargets , mDataProp , sTitle in aoColumnsRef" and send back to datatables now its working :)